# Who introduced the Kite to Smullyan's combinator birds?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I am reading To Mock a Mockingbird by Raymond Smullyan. I was led to it by various people describing the lambda calculus combinators using Smullyan's ornithological notation, such as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAnLQ9jwN-E&t=461s) and [this paper](http://dkeenan.com/Lambda/). but I am confused about one thing. Both people use the bird "kestrel" for true and "kite" for false. Kestrel is the bird where A(Bx) = B, and Smullyan does indeed include that bird in the "Hopeless Egocentricity" section. Keenan, in the first link, describes the Kite as "The Kite ignores what it hears and always responds with the Idiot song, so it is the KI bird." The Kite is the Kestrel(Idiot) bird, which in the second link is described as a bird where Ki(Ax) = x.

But I have looked and as far as I can tell Smullyan never mentions the kite, nor does he mention a bird that is the Kestrel listening to the Idiot or where A(Bx) = x in the "Who's Who Among the Birds" section. I searched for 'Kite' in the Google Books version of TMAM and came up with nothing.

My question: Is the kite in TMAM and I missed it? And if Smullyan didn't invent the Kite, who did? And why do people describe it as if it came from TMAM when it didn't?

Comment: $\mathsf K$ and $\mathsf I$ are *combinators*. See [Combinatory Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-combinatory/#CombTermTheiMainProp).

Comment: +1 I have to read the To Mock a Mockingbird mentioned by the OP.

Comment: The explanantion "The Kestrel's response to hearing a song $x$ is (a song which describes) a bird which responds with $x$ no matter what it hears" corresponds to the def of the combinator $\mathsf K$ as $\mathsf K xy=x$. Thus, irrespective of the value of $x$ for argument $y$, the $\mathsf K$-onstant combinator produces $x$ as output.

Comment: The combinator $\mathsf I$ is defined as $\mathsf Ix=x$, and is the $\mathsf I$-dentity combinator. Thus, the $\mathsf {KI}$ combinator gives us: $\mathsf {KI}x=\mathsf I$. "The Kite ignores what it hears and always responds with the Idiot song, so it is the KI bird."

Comment: Maybe useful into Melvin Fitting & Brian Rayman (editors), [Raymond Smullyan on Self Reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=cbRGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR6), Springer (2017): **Chapter 6** *Some Tweets About Mockingbirds* by Rick Statman.

Comment: Sorry Mauro, to clarify, I understand the origin of the name (ki)te, and I understand what the K and I combinators are and what KI means. I just was surprised that Smullyan never seemed to mention this combination or give it a bird name and I'm wondering who originally did.

Comment: But thank you for the link to the Fitting & Rayman book.

Comment: Notice the notation you use is wrong, or at least different to the one used in TMAM: the Kestrel is defined as the bird K such that Kxy = x; note that Kxy is shorthand for (Kx)y, which is very different to K(xy). Like wise, KIxy = Iy = y, which is very different to KI(xy) which equals I.

Comment: As for the "Kite", I don't know who introduced the name, but the bird itself - as KI - does appear in TMAM, in Chapter 23 - _Logical Birds_: "For t, I take the kestrel K; for f, I take the bird KI. And so, when we are discussing propositional logic, I use t synonymously with K and f synonymously with KI." (page 212 in the first edition).

Answer (score 1):

I found this ([here](http://chicken.kitten-technologies.co.uk/cache/4/combinator-birds/0.1/combinator-birds.scm)) by googling.

```
;; A few birds and aliases not necessarily given in the book
  ;; but discussed in David Keenan's http://dkeenan.com/Lambda/
  (define identity-bird*   (Î» (x y) (x y)))
  (define kite             (Î» (x y) y))
  (define konstant-mocker  (Î» (x y) (y y)))
  (define crossed-konstant-mocker (Î» (x y) (x x)))
  (define idiot-bird* identity-bird*)
  (define pairing vireo))
```

Comment: I was going to mark this the answer, but now I don't know if it does. All it says is that Keenan used it and Smullyan didn't, which I already knew because the question linked to a Keenan paper where he's talking about it. Maybe Keenan introduced the Kite, but this doesn't confirm that.